# Micro component to send signal to skin nerves (non-invasive)

Tags: identification

I want to build a device that can send a signal directly to skin, so that the user could “sense” when the signal is on or off.

I know transcutaneous electrical nerve stimulation (TENS) can accomplish this, but they’re rather large and bulky; I need something very small, closer to 1mm in size.

Does anyone know of a simple, tiny, cheap way to accomplish such a task?

Comment: Definitely not around a mm in size.

Comment: Large and bulky are relative terms. The TENS electronic box measures 4X2.5X1 inches and weighs a couple of ounces. The electrode is 40X40 mm which I'm sure is sized to achieve the desired medical results.. I assume your 1 mm requirement refers only to the electrodes. Allowing for a removable cable between the box and the electrode alone makes 1 mm very unrealistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resistor, when current flows through them they get hot.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, I wonder how quickly the signal can change though given dissipation time. If I wanted to send a Morse code signal to the skin for example, it may take too long as I have to wait for cooling down / warming up times. Can you think of anything more instant? I was looking into maybe using actuators, found one small enough called “Squiggle Motor” but it doesn’t seem to be for sale.

Comment: thermal printers work on this principle, the speed of the skin is the limit

Comment: mouser.com  have demosnstration kits for  the squiggle motor  they are not cheap!

Comment: thank you, looking into existing `thermal printer` components I think will be a viable path!